# How to export an environment variable from an action whose value is computed by a shell script?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, github-actions

I have created a GitHub action (written in JavaScript) that installs software from a git repo and exports some environment variables for use in workflows running the action. The installation process is performed using Bash scripts. For environment variables with a fixed value, this is easily done by calling `core.exportVariable(name, value)`. But I also need to export the git hash for the installed version. This hash can be easily computed in the Bash scripts (and it should be computed there to avoid race conditions). What will be the most clean solution for passing the hash value back to the JavaScript code that calls the Bash scripts? `@actions/exec` takes input parameters but doesn't support output parameters. `@actions/exec` can capture process output but I very much prefer to avoid an hack based on parsing output.

Comment: Just write the git hash to a known file and read that file via JS. e.g. `echo $HASH > ./git-hash`.

Comment: @aknosis Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for API solution that I might have missed.